# Error while starting Neo4j Database

Tags: neo4j, timeout, bootstrapping

Whenever I try to start my neo4j sever on local machine using:

```
sudo service neo4j-service start
```

At first I got the error something like this:

```
 Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [19953]... waiting for server to be ready... Failed to start within 
120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

but, when I commented all those fields in neo4j-wrapper.conf file, the errors reduced to:

```
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [20409]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Does anyone have any idea what I should do?
P.S. : mine is neo4j 2.1.3
I have tried every possible solution, but its not working.

Comment: The error message you see already contains the advice "please check the logs" ;-)

Comment: I am getting this exception... :- "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:125)
 at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:57)"

Comment: amend the **full** stacktrace to your question above

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try the following ?

change the port number from 1337 to a different one like 1339 in neo4j.properties file Inside conf folder.

remote_shell_port = 1339